# How do I filter a stream in dart after a certain criteria?

Tags: java, dart, java-stream

Lets say I have a stream of persons and I want to filter them by the age being >= 40.
I know that in Java I can do something like this:

```
lp.stream().filter(p->p.getAKge()>=40).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I'm new to dart so I don't really know what would be the equivalent of this functionality in this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except slight syntax differences use [`where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) on the source and job done.

```
lp.where((p) => p.getAge() >= 40).forEach((p) => print(p));
```